# Multiindex dataframe as a sum of existing Multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, multi-index

I have a dataFrame like this

```
             1523                               ...  2175                          
         electric  SS%  SC%   SC PV_production  ...  NGIP   LOLP     Ei E_tg   E_fg
Timestep                                        ...                                
1           0.000  0.0  0.0  0.0             0  ...  True  False  0.000  0.0  0.000
2           0.000  0.0  0.0  0.0             0  ...  True  False  0.000  0.0  0.000
3           0.000  0.0  0.0  0.0             0  ...  True  False  0.000  0.0  0.000
4           0.000  0.0  0.0  0.0             0  ...  True  False  0.000  0.0  0.000
5           0.000  0.0  0.0  0.0             0  ...  True  False  0.000  0.0  0.000
          ...  ...  ...  ...           ...  ...   ...    ...    ...  ...    ...
8756        0.027  0.0  0.0  0.0             0  ...  True   True -0.006  0.0  0.006
8757        0.000  0.0  0.0  0.0             0  ...  True  False  0.000  0.0  0.000
8758        0.000  0.0  0.0  0.0             0  ...  True  False  0.000  0.0  0.000
8759        0.000  0.0  0.0  0.0             0  ...  True  False  0.000  0.0  0.000
8760        0.000  0.0  0.0  0.0             0  ...  True  False  0.000  0.0  0.000
```

and I would like to get a new similar DataFrame, as a copy of this one, with same Headers on two levels but with 1 row being the sum of the 8760 data. Tried with a for loop passing through a dictionary before going back to a dataframe. I succeed in the first column, but I am not able to append other resulsts:

> dict_data = {}
>
> for i in data_multi.columns.levels[0]:
> dict_data[i] = data_multi[(i,'electric')].sum()

this works with electric column, but if I do the same with PV_production, I am not able to append the sum to the same related key of dict_data dictionary. If I try to append or extend a key I get ('numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'extend') error.

Let's say I have this:

```
             1589                   1523              
         electric PV_production electric PV_production
Timestep                                              
1          10.000             0    0.000             0
2          10.000             0    0.000             0
3          10.000             0    0.000             0
4          10.000             0    0.000             0
5         100.000             0    0.000             0
6         300.000             0    0.027             0
7         600.000             0    0.027             0
8         900.000             0    0.000             0
9         900.000             7    0.000             0
10        600.000           148    0.000             9
11        900.000           273    0.027            16
```

and want to get this:

```
             1589                   1523              
         electric PV_production electric PV_production
Timestep                                              
1          4340.0           328    0.061            25
```

as the sum of all the values in the column, but keeping the multi header scheme

Comment: please post minimal reproducible example

Comment: Do you mean of the DataFrame, I can add the head of part of the DataFrame